# How to prevent form submit, do some JavaScript and then run the form while passing data into NODE?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, ejs

I'm working on a Personal Information page (see figure below) which I want the user to change their credentials while checking the old password before the form is submitted. This is the sequence of events I'm looking for.

1. The user changed some data and pressed the button.
2. (client-side) Alert to retrieve old password from the user.
3. (client-side) Pass the old password in NODE to check if correct.
4. (server-side) Change the data from step 1.

The above sequence of events may not be the best way of achieving this, so I'm happy to hear your suggestion.

EJS:

```
<form id="personalInfoForm">
    <input type="text" name="settings_f_name" value="<%= data[0].value %>" placeholder="Enter new first name"> 
    <input type="text" name="settings_l_name" value="<%= data[1].value %>" placeholder="Enter new last name"> 
    <input type="email" name="settings_email" value="<%= data[2].value %>" placeholder="Enter new email-address" required> 
    <input type="password" name="settings_password" placeholder="Enter password"> 
    <input type="password" name="settings_password_confirmed"  placeholder="Confirm your password"> 

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto">Update Profile</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
const personalInfoForm = document.getElementById("personalInfoForm");

personalInfoForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var password;
    var person = prompt("Please enter your old password:", "");
    if (person == null || person == "") {
      password = "Please provide your old password in order to submit the request.";
    } else {
      password = "Your personal information have changed.";
    }

    alert(password);

    //CALL action='/setNewPersonalInformation' method='POST'
    //check if old password matches
    //change credentials
});
```

NODE:

```
router.post('/setNewPersonalInformation', redirectLogin, async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.session.userId;
    let f_name = req.body.settings_f_name;
    let l_name = req.body.settings_l_name;
    let email = req.body.settings_email;
    let password_a = req.body.settings_password;
    let password_b = req.body.settings_password_confirmed;
    let hashedPass = 0;
    let sqlQuery = "";
    let db_data = [];
    
    //***********************************
    //CHECK IF OLD PASSWORD MATCHES AND THEN PROCEED
    //***********************************


    //Check if password matches the confirmed password
    if(password_a == password_b){

        let password_to_hash = password_a;
        try{
            hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(password_to_hash, saltRounds);
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        db_data = [f_name, l_name, email, hashedPass, id]; //Data to change on the database
        sqlQuery = "UPDATE student_demographics SET first_name = ?, last_name = ?, email = ?, password = ? WHERE id = ?";
        

        getConnection().query(sqlQuery, db_data, async (err, results, fields) => {
            //Do changes
        });
    }
});
```

[image: demo 1]

I have tried using npm `sweetalert` `sweetalert2` and `alert-node` but couldn't even get a simple alert. I also had a look on `body-parser` but from what I understood it has access to DOM elements (correct me if I'm wrong). I'm not sure how to work with it using `alert`/`prompt`.

Comment: Have you looked at the console? If there's a syntax error somewhere in that code you don't show, the function is never executed.

Comment: @Teemu, no errors or-so-ever in the console. the prompt executes as expected. When I change the form from `<form id="personalInfoForm">` to `<form action="/setNewPersonalInformation" method="POST">` also works okay, but i don't verify the old password. Doing those together will result in submitting the form without executing the JS function.

Comment: But the alert doesn't? In that case you've denied the alert windows from the current page (ticked the checkbox when browser asked something like "Don't open messages on this page.")

Comment: Sorry, my bad. When doing `<form id="personalInfoForm" action="/setNewPersonalInformation" method="POST">` will execute JS but not Node as I prevent the event